# Pack method resizing JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I want to write a simple application in which frame displays a given image and takes its size.

My problem is that `pack` method increases `contentPane's` width and I'm not sure why it happens so. Thank you in advance.

Here is the code:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

                MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public MyFrame() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(null);
    contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 0, 0));
    MapPanel map=new MapPanel("img/strawberry.jpg");
    map.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 0, 0));
    contentPane.add(map);

    setContentPane(contentPane);
}

}

/**
 * My panel containing the image
 */

public class MapPanel extends JPanel {

private BufferedImage img=null;
/**
 * Create the panel.
 */
public MapPanel(String url){
        super();
        try{
            img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(url));
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.setBorder(null);
        Dimension imgsize=new Dimension(img.getWidth(),img.getHeight());
        setPreferredSize(imgsize);
        setSize(imgsize);
        setMinimumSize(imgsize);
        setMaximumSize(imgsize);

}

@Override
public void paintComponent( Graphics g ){
    super.paintComponent( g );

    Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g;
    g2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (img != null) {
         return new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
      }
      return super.getPreferredSize(); // default
   }
}
```

Comment: *"My problem is that pack method increases contentPane's width"* - By this, what do you mean?  The code seems to work just fine and as expected for me

Comment: Although I'd get rid of `setPreferred/Minimum/MaximumSize` and `setSize`

Comment: In some cases it worked for me too, but if i give a small image (80x80) it's resized to 124x80.

Comment: Windows have an automatic minimum size placed on them to ensure that the window buttons are displayed correctly, if your content size falls below this, the window will automatically be sized to it's minimum size instead

Comment: Thanks a lot, now is clear.

Answer (score 0):

According to `Window`'s `pack` method javadoc:

> Causes this Window to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents. The resulting width and height of the window are automatically enlarged if either of dimensions is less than the minimum size as specified by the previous call to the setMinimumSize method.
>   If the window and/or its owner are not displayable yet, both of them are made displayable before calculating the preferred size. The Window is validated after its size is being calculated.

`MyFrame` extends `JFRame`, which extends `Window`